# What is the time complexity of Collection.toArray()?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, collections, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the method `Collection.toArray()`? is it O(n), if yes than what benefits does it offer over looping and individually assigning the values in the list to an array( beside nice look and some extra effort of course).

Comment: `Collections` doesn't have a `toArray` method. Do you mean the `Collection` interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `toArray()` method is abstract, speaking about its time complexity in general makes no sense.

However, for native implementations, the complexity is indeed `O(n)`. It is noteworthy that `Collection` is a subinterface of `Iterable`. It would we quite absurd to implement an `Iterable` which cannot be efficiently iterated over.

The fact that the implementation of `toArray()` is kept open, leaves space for optimizations. There may be approaches faster than building the array using simple iteration (array copying, running in multiple threads...). However, the [default implementaion](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toArray%28%29) in `AbstractCollection` uses the exact approach that you mention in your question.

Comment: The generic iterable case should be usually `n x O(Iterator#next())` but although I don't know of one, it shouldn't be too hard to come up with a special collection that is not O(1) for `next()`.

Comment: @zapl That's definitely true, but not for native implementations, which is the case I believe the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

A call of `toArray()` on any collection walks the entire collection. For all collections from `java.util` this means O(n) timing. Of course implementations that are slower than O(n) can be constructed as well, but O(n) provides a lower bound for the timing, because you have to traverse the entire collection.

You call `toArray()` when you need to call an API that specifically asks for an array, or in situations when you want to make a copy of your collection for any reason. In general, you do not want to overuse `toArray()`, because it allocates additional memory sufficient to fit all elements of your collection.